# WCF REST reading JSON request body

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, wcf

I've been trying for a week now to understand how to get and read the request body of an HttpRequest as JSON (it is sent to me in JSON).I think in my case it's a WCF RESTful service but I'm not sure.  So far the furthest I've come is by using `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()` which gives me the content of the request body but instead of as JSON it shows it as a weird xml translation of it, like this:

```
<root type="object">
<reqPrices type="object">
<regionID type="null"/>
<cityCode type="string">New York</cityCode>
<userName type="string">test</Password>
</obj>
</root>
```

I've got an IService class with the following code:

```
namespace TBServices.Services.SilWebApi
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceSilWebApi
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "prices",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Stream DoWorkPrices();
     }
}
```

and a Service with the following code:

```
    namespace TBServices.Services.SilWebApi
    {
        [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
        public class ServiceSilWebApi : BaseService, IServiceSilWebApi
        {
            ...
             public Stream DoWorkPrices()
            {   
              string aa = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();
              return new Stream();
            }
            ...
         }
     }
```

The relevant section in the config file is:

```
<service name="TBServices.Services.SilWebApi.ServiceSilWebApi">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" contract="TBServices.Services.SilWebApi.IServiceSilWebApi" />
 </service>
```

I'm new to WCF/REST/SOAP/Web services, and I've read anything I could find about what I'm trying to do, both here and in MSDN, but I still can't figure it out. I've already seen this link with a very similiar question to mine: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3b6307e-886c-4b8a-a7ff-00cd9490520b/read-incoming-data-as-json-wcf?forum=wcf, but I don't understand most of it. 
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

If you receive data using POST only, your method needs an argument to receive the POST data:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "prices",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Stream DoWorkPrices(string jsonData);
```

Comment: thanks, but I've tried it already and then it doesn't even go to this function in runtime, like it doesn't recognize it as matching